# Issue to find out the TcpClient disconnected due to network lost

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, tcpclient

I am working on a TcpClient Asynchronous requesting WPF project. In which I have written some code when ever client gets disconnected with out network lost due to socket disconnected. Its working fine, and when the socket is removed/unplugged also on the server side no event is firing or no exception recieved to make the client status disconnected. I have seen about this issue in many sites, every where people used to say to use the `Socket.Poll` method but which is not working in my case. The `SelectMode.SelectRead` is always returning true when the client connected or disconnected, so I cant find any alternative.

So, I am posting my question here to know how to find when a client socket is unplugged/network access has been lost in asynchronous mode. I have tried with following code, any how its not working.

```
    void CheckSocketStatus()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                if(!mobjClient.Client.Poll(0,SelectMode.SelectWrite))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(SocketException soex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that this cannot be used to detect certain connection problems as by the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.poll.aspx) that states:

> This method cannot detect certain kinds of connection problems, such as a broken network cable, or that the remote host was shut down ungracefully. You must attempt to send or receive data to detect these kinds of errors.

You should probably consider not relying on a persistent connection and instead open/close it on demand. Nevertheless, if you need some kind of connection state information, the unfortunate conclusion is that the underlying architecture does not provide it. You'll have to do it by periodically exchanging packets and catching errors.

This is also what the documentation on the [Connected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connected.aspx) property of TcpClient suggests:

> Because the Connected property only reflects the state of the connection as of the most recent operation, you should attempt to send or receive a message to determine the current state. After the message send fails, this property no longer returns true. Note that this behavior is by design. You cannot reliably test the state of the connection because, in the time between the test and a send/receive, the connection could have been lost. Your code should assume the socket is connected, and gracefully handle failed transmissions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Any how I am working on this for last two days. I will reply to you when it works.

Comment: One thing that I thought of, but it's a bit dangerous is to use techniques similar to port scanners. Maybe it is possible to find in the TCP standard a way that you can send a certain packet that will not affect your established connection, but to which the other endpoint will reply. You could then craft this probe in your check method. But I don't know what e.g. happens when you send a SYN packet through a connection that is already established. Such a packet should not go up to the application layer on the other side. I would certainly be interested in the solution that you'll find.

Comment: Right now i dint find a correct solution, but some how manually managing it. When the client disconnected, then at server side I am forcely closing the particualr client's connection also.

Comment: I have used the force logout in my application. Any how sending and recieveing data will put some type of burden/dependency on my application.  Any how thanks for your answer.

Comment: Okay, too bad there's no better way to deal with this, but anyway, thanks for the heads up.